Problem with VBA buttons in Word Template
I'm creating a Word Template .dotm. In this template I add information about products from a spreadsheet, and the user can select products using a list and searchbox, and for each product selected it displays the information about the product from the spreadsheet in markdown in the Word template (<<Example>>).
I want to get the name of all the products selected and I want to show a list at the end of the Word document with name and price of products. So I created an Array, and every time a product is added, this array receives the name and the price of it. The problem is the button that is supposed to replace the markdown with the information in the array is not working. But if I use F5 to execute the Sub, it works...
Dim products() As Variant

' The sub where I add products

Sub determinePrice()

    selectedRegion = ActiveDocument.ComboBox1.Value 
    
    Dim price As Variant

    Select Case selectedRegion
        Case "A"
            preco = dataArray(excelRowIndex, 11) 
        Case "B"
            preco = dataArray(excelRowIndex, 12)
    End Select

    If IsNumeric(preco) Then
        Call RetrieveTotalPreco
        totalPrice = totalPrice + price
        price = Format(price, "Currency")
    End If
    
    Call AddProduct(dataArray(excelRowIndex, 2), price)
    
    replaceText "<<Price>>", CStr(price)
    StoreTotalPrice

End Sub

Sub AddProduct(name As Variant, price As Variant)
    Dim currentSize As Long
    Dim tempMatrix() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    currentSize = UBound(products, 1) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    If currentSize < 0 Then currentSize = 0
    
    ReDim tempMatrix(0 To currentSize, 0 To 1)
    
    If currentSize > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(products, 1)
            tempMatrix(i, 0) = products(i, 0)
            tempMatrix(i, 1) = products(i, 1)
        Next i
    End If
        
    
    ' Add new product do temp matrix
    tempMatrix(currentSize, 0) = name
    tempMatrix(currentSize, 1) = price
    
  
    products = tempMatrix

End Sub

Private Sub GenerateQuotation_Click()
    Call addFinalPrice    
    Call SaveAsPdf
End Sub

Sub addFinalPrice()
    Dim textMatrixNames As Variant
    Dim textMatrixPrices As Variant
 
    For i = LBound(products) To UBound(products)
        textMatrixNames = textMatrixNames & products(i, 0) & vbCrLf
        textMatrixPrices = textMatrixPrices & Format(products(i, 1), "Currency") & vbCrLf
    Next i
    
    replaceText "<<AllProductsNames>>", textMatrixNames
    replaceText "<<AllProductsPrices>>", textMatrixPrices
End Sub



It works, but only if I F5 on "GenerateQuotation". The button doesn't work. The values disappear when I click on the button.
I tried everything I know but I couldn't fix this. The problem seems to be in the communication between the button code in the template and the array in the document created from the template.

Yes, it's an ActiveX control.  I actually fixed it by using a different approach, but I'd still like to understand what I was doing wrong.
The button actually runs the Sub, I was testing it with MsgBoxes. It seems that the variable isn't holding the values from the array but idk why.
In the new approach, I created a table at the end of the document, so every time I add a product, the Sub DeterminePrice also adds a row to this table and puts the name at one column and price at the other. It avoids storing data in the array by creating and inserting the data at the same Sub.

Glad you fixed it. Personally I just wouldn't rely on a VBA variable retaining value if the code wasn't running continuously. If you really needed that, you could consider using named Word Variables (which are name-value pairs stored in the document) but I would guess in most cases there is a simpler solution.
